# Clustering of a graph of file names to regroup files in folders

Tags: algorithm, cluster-analysis

I'm looking for known good algorithms for (fuzzy) clustering of similar file names found in a hierarchy of folders.

To remain within SO rules and spirit, let me explain the context in detail, so that your answers can be concise rather than generic.

---

#### Context

My goal is to develop an application which:

- takes a set of files (content and names)
- compares filenames to **identify clusters**
- compares contents to find duplicates (this is off scope)
- suggest files deletions and file regrouping **based on identified clusters** and identical contents.

For example, given 3 folders:

- `folder 1`: `file_1`, `file_7`, `file_23`, ...
- `folder 2`: duplicate of `file_1`, ...
- `folder 3`: `file_5`, ...

I would suggest to:

- delete the duplicate of `file_1` in `folder 2`, rather than in `folder 1`, because there is a larger part of the cluster in `folder 1`.
- move `file_5` from `folder 3` to `folder 1`, because it would extend the existing cluster.

I've read about two concepts:

- [String metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metrics), and various distances between two strings.
- [Cluster analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis).

I assume I'm able to create a graph where nodes are file names and edge are distances (I've posted a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024413/calculating-distances-between-elements-in-a-large-set-of-file-names-to-regroup-s) for distance calculation).

It seems [this kind of algorithm](http://www.ludowaltman.nl/slm/) would be able to find clusters from this graph.

---

#### Question

Being a programmer, not a mathematician, I would appreciate to have some recommendations on best directions to look for efficient clustering algorithms applicable to this specific case of clustering file names (based on existing projects with comparable goals).

Comment: For moderators: Please note that most of the question is to explain the context, to narrow the possible answers, and the last paragraph, which is the actual question is quite clear about what is expected "best directions to look for efficient clustering algorithms applicable to this specific case." The fist answer is quite specific, not generic. I'm willing to narrow furthermore, but don't see exactly how. Please advise.

Comment: This question seems to be more appropriate at http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo: [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clustering) returns 50,000 results while [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/search?q=clustering) does not provide 500. Not to mention the content is less related. I have tried [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) but I had a second thought about that, and moved the question here in the end.

Comment: Among @JimLewis, DavidEisenstat, LegoStormtroopr, RuchiraGayanRanaweera, OptimusCrime (who have voted to hold the question), it seems nobody cares about answering my comment-question and providing more explanation about the reason why they don't want people to provide more answers. I remember well that when it's time to vote for community moderators, there are many candidates who insist on viewing themselves as a coach, a mentor open to communication rather than a tough censor, and that's why i vote for them. Come on... consider reopening this question, or provide some advice.

Comment: I think it's a neat question and I don't see why it was closed. I too am looking to do unsupervised clustering of filenames (each file just has a suffix with a few characters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are looking for good clustering algorithms, I won't go into similarity scores of text and documents. However, you may find research materials in `Natural Language Processing` helpful. You can even do `Topic Modeling` when it involves context of the document.

It sounds like you do not want to dig into too much Math in the algorithms. I will suggest a simple approach (below).

Assuming you have obtained a thresholded similarity graph, the graph can be expressed as a matrix or a dictionary of list. The graph can be sparse or dense after thresholding.

If it is quite dense, try [Spectral Clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_clustering).

If it is sparse, try [Affinity Propagation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affinity_propagation).

They are both well documented and implemented in most programming languages used in data science. For examples, in `Python`, you have [Scikit-Learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/clustering.html); in `R`, you have [This](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Cluster.html).

Interesting concept you proposed. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you Mai. You give me interesting tracks to explore. Truly appreciated. I'm indeed looking for simple clustering methods since I'm dealing with strings that have no meaning further than naming a file, and at most are using technical tricks like numbering similar files with a variable suffix. I'm learning a lot...

Comment: @mins If you are looking for simple fuzzy string matching, you can try  https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.get_close_matches

Comment: ok. It seems distance is based on Ratcliff-Obershelp method, I've also in my bag Levenshtein one's. I plan to have my own implementation in Java. Other [string comparison methods](http://www.morfoedro.it/doc.php?n=223&lang=en), I'll likely try several.

Comment: @mins Very hardworking my friend!